# Solve $\dot{x}(t)+tx(t)=tx(t)^{2}$ using integrating factors method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**Question:**
Solve $\dot{x}(t)+tx(t)=tx(t)^{2}$ using integrating factors method (give the general solution).

**My attempt:**
$e^{\int tdt} = e^{\frac{1}{2}t^{2}}$.

$e^{\frac{1}{2}t^{2}} \dot{x}(t)+e^{\frac{1}{2}t^{2}}tx(t) = e^{\frac{1}{2}t^{2}}tx(t)^{2}$

$\frac{d}{dt} [e^{\frac{1}{2}t^{2}}x] = \int e^{\frac{1}{2}t^{2}}tx(t)^{2}dt$

I am stuck on integrating the RHS.

Comment: Or treat it as Bernoulli equation and consider $y=x^{-1}$. Then you get a linear DE and can apply an integrating factor.

Comment: I tried the substitution and posted it as an aswer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{d}{dt} [e^{\frac{1}{2}t^{2}}x] = \int e^{\frac{1}{2}t^{2}}tx(t)^{2}dt$$
This should be:
$$\frac{d}{dt} [e^{\frac{1}{2}t^{2}}x] =  e^{\frac{1}{2}t^{2}}tx(t)^{2}$$
Separate before to integrate.
$$\dfrac 1{x^2e^t}\frac{d}{dt} [e^{\frac{1}{2}t^{2}}x] =  e^{-\frac{1}{2}t^{2}}t$$
$$\dfrac 1{x^2e^t}{d} [e^{\frac{1}{2}t^{2}}x] =  e^{-\frac{1}{2}t^{2}}t dt$$
$$ \int \dfrac 1{x^2e^t}{d} [e^{\frac{1}{2}t^{2}}x] =\int  e^{-\frac{1}{2}t^{2}}t dt$$

Answer (score 0):

I tried substitution like somebody suggested.
Take $u=x(t)^{-1}$. $u'=-x(t)^{-2}x'(t)$
Divide equation by $x(t)^{2}$ gives
$$
\dot{x}(t)x(t)^{-2}+tx(t)^{-1}=t
$$
Substitute now in equation gives
$$
-u'+tu=t
$$
Multiply by $e^{\frac{1}{2}t^{2}}$ because $e^{\int tdt} = e^{\frac{1}{2}t^{2}}$

$$
-e^{\frac{1}{2}t^{2}}u' + e^{\frac{1}{2}t^{2}}tu = e^{\frac{1}{2}t^{2}}t
$$
This gives
$$
-\frac{du}{dt} [e^{\frac{1}{2}t^{2}} u] = \int e^{\frac{1}{2}t^{2}}
$$
$$
-u = \frac{C}{e^{\frac{1}{2}t^{2}}}
$$

$$
x(t) = -\frac{e^{\frac{1}{2}t^{2}}}{C}
$$